# Create FreeBSD install image on USB stick from Windows

Tags: windows, freebsd, system-installation

I want to create a install media on a USB memory stick to install FreeBSB 10.3.

I've downloaded a *-memstick.img* release then I followed the [Procedure 2.2](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/bsdinstall-pre.html) from the FreeBSD handbook to copy the *img* file to the key. The process seems OK since I get a "Done" message at the end.

But then the USB drive becomes unreadable from my Windows 7 OS. Is it normal or does it mean there's a problem with the image creation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds about right: MS-Windows can only read FAT and NTFS file-systems, the usb will no-longer be one of those two. Unix systems do not use these as there main file-system (only for auxiliary data disks, to be compatible with MS-Windows), as they do not support all of the features that Unix needs.

Therefore this is not a sight that it will not work, but a bit of a sign that it will.

Answer (score 0):

You must have 2 USB stick: In first USB copy DVD1.iso file and in second USB copy memstick.img file. 
"But then the USB drive becomes unreadable from my Windows 7 OS" - You can fix the flash drive by formatting the USB flash drive in Linux or another operating system except windows operating system ! I hope I helped you! (^_^)